# SQL Query Not making Sense to me

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I think my where clause is wrong.

My dilemma is, if user don't have a record in tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance that means they are taking all of it.

So if user don't have a record in tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance I want them to come back as a result.
I also want them to come back if they do have a record in tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance and it matches using LIKE or equal.

```
SELECT
[dbo].[tbl_users].*, [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].*
     FROM
[dbo].[tbl_users]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance] ON [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].buyerId = [dbo].[tbl_users].id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_dentalInsurance] ON [dbo].[tbl_dentalInsurance].id = [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].dentalInsuranceId
    WHERE
(
    (
        [dbo].[tbl_dentalInsurance].companyName LIKE '%Cigna%'
        OR [dbo].[tbl_dentalInsurance].companyName = ''
    )
    AND(
        [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].ppo = 1
        OR [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].ppo = ''
    )
    AND(
        [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].hmo = 0
        OR [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].hmo = ''
    )
)
```

Comment: You should really try using aliases for your tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you're using LEFT JOINS, if there's no matching records on the "right" side of the join, all of those right-side fields will be `NULL`, not empty strings. You'd have to explicitly check for that with `.... OR whatever IS NULL`, as NULL cannot ever be equal to anything, including itself.

Comment: So dose this make sense?? 

`WHERE
 (
  (
   [dbo].[tbl_dentalInsurance].companyName LIKE '%Cigna%'
   OR [dbo].[tbl_dentalInsurance].companyName IS NULL
  )
  AND(
   [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].ppo = 1
   OR [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].ppo IS NULL
  )
  AND(
   [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].hmo = 0
   OR [dbo].[tbl_dentalBuyerInsurance].hmo IS NULL
  )
 )`

Answer (score 1):

```
[dbo].[tbl_dentalInsurance].companyName LIKE '%Cigna%'
        OR [dbo].[tbl_dentalInsurance].companyName = ''
```

that means that you are allowinf empty strings, that's your first mistake, and how said MarcB if you are looking for null values so the query is :

```
[dbo].[tbl_dentalInsurance].companyName LIKE '%Cigna%'
        OR [dbo].[tbl_dentalInsurance].companyName is null
```

if you are allowing empty string so you have to use len function for validate values with lenght 0

saludos